# Where can emails be sniffed from?

Tags: email, man-in-the-middle

I understand that you should not send private information in emails due, in part, to the fact that this traffic is usually unencrypted and can therefore be sniffed while in transit.

Where would a person need to be in order to sniff this traffic?  I'm assuming that they either need to be on the same network as the sending or receiving end of the email.

Is this correct?  Could someone potentially find a way to sniff the traffic even if they are not on the same network as the sending/receiving end?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm assuming that they either need to be on the same network as the sending or receiving end of the email.

There are lot more possibilities:

- In the sending or receiving network. This vector could be mostly eliminated when sending/receiving the mail with TLS, at least if the certificates are correctly validated (which is mostly the case in this step of delivery).
- On any of the mail servers in between. Since the mail is delivered hop by hop it is available in clear on each of the hops, even if the transport is protected with TLS. This includes the receiving mail server, the final mail server which make the mail available to the recipient and any mail server on the path between.
- In any position in the network between the sending and receiving mail server, where it is possible to spoof DNS. Since the path of the delivery is controlled by DNS MX records the attacker could divert the mail to its own system. TLS alone will not help here, but adding DNSSec will help. Unfortunately it is not much used yet which means that nobody will make sure that any answer is signed by DNSSec (too much could break).
- In any position in the network between the sending and receiving mail server, where the attacker can sniff or even modify the traffic. Passive sniffing is enough if the transfer is not protected with TLS. In case of TLS the attacker could make sure that STARTTLS gets rejected and thus the mail gets transferred without TLS. Or it could do man in the middle for TLS, since certificates at this step of delivery are usually not properly validated (too much could break). Note that such a position could also be reached by diverting the routes, like in [BGP spoofing](http://www.bgpmon.net/bgp-routing-incidents-in-2014-malicious-or-not/).

Thus if you really need to protect the contents of the mail you need to use end-to-end encryption with S/MIME or PGP instead of no encryption or hop-by-hop encryption. This of course assumes that you have the correct key of the target, i.e. not [spoofed](http://www.asheesh.org/note/debian/short-key-ids-are-bad-news.html) and not just asking a PGP key server and fully trusting the response.